# ESXi Passthrough hard drive to use ZFS on VM

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, zfs

I have ESXI 6.7 installed on my r710.  I have 1 2TB drive that's being used as the boot drive for ESXi and the VMs.  I have 3 4TB drives that will be large storage.  I want to send the 4TB disks directly to the VM so the raid can be handled with ZFS.  How do I pass the drives directly to the VM?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm really understanding you - but would something like running FreeNAS or NAS4Free and mapping hard drives to ESXi via iSCSI work?

Answer (score 4):

There are several options. If the Boot drive is located in the same PCI RAID Controller you can't pass-through the entire controller.

Try using RDM option which will paravirtualize hard disks to the VM. To make this, present all the drives as RAID-0 to the ESXi.
Also, you can make an RDM pointer to each hard disk.

You can use these links:

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2046370

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1017530

Answer (score 0):

I used this procedure to do same for my truenas
https://gist.github.com/Hengjie/1520114890bebe8f805d337af4b3a064

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/514481)